# Same code is not working for changing the selector type?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap navbar that contains some menus option. When i click on any menu, it should display the id and loads the corresponding code.

Below is the code:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(){
  alert(this.id);
  window.location.href = "admin-editcp.php";
  //var NavId = this.id;
  //fxnNavClicked(NavId);
});
```

Its displaying correct id but not loading the new page.

When i change the selector type from nav a to testbutton as

```
$('#testbutton').on('click', function(){
  alert(this.id);
  window.location.href = "admin-editcp.php";
  //var NavId = this.id;
  //fxnNavClicked(NavId);
});
```

It works for me..
Still not able to find the cause of such issue or mistake?????

Leads will be appreciated

Below is html code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav temp-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="INavTheHotel">The Hotel</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" >Rooms <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="" id="INavSemiDeluxe">Semi Deluxe Rooms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="INavDeluxe">Deluxe Rooms</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>

        <li><a href="" id="INavAroundus">around us</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="INavTariff">tariff</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="INavContact">Contact</a></li>   

    </ul>

</div>


<button type="button btn-white" id="testbutton" class="default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Are the selectors pointing to the same element? It would help to see your HTML here.

Comment: Please paste your HTML.

Comment: Are the selectors pointing to the same element?  Please share your HTML so that we can check

Comment: No both are diff..
As one is button and another is bootstrap navbar

<button type="button btn-white" id="testbutton" class="default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>


<ul class="nav navbar-nav temp-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="" id="INavTheHotel">The Hotel</a></li>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: @VPartapSinghSalathia: The first selector doesn't match anything in that HTML.  So it wouldn't invoke the click handler at all.  Not sure how it's "displaying the correct id" in your testing.  I suspect you've made an incorrect assumption somewhere in your testing.

Comment: @David, its clear I was also in doubt for the nav selector, so just tell me how to over come from this.
But How, it display the correct id of all menus

Comment: If you're clicking an `a` element, then the broswer will be sent to the URL specified in the `href`, not your `window.location` set in JS. Changing to a `button` fixes that problem. You need to add a `preventDefault()` call if you want to use the `a` element. Also, please use the `edit` button to add code to the question. Code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: your first selector is wrong, it searches for an `<nav>` element instead of the class `.nav`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `preventDefault()` for this...

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
    window.location.href = "admin-editcp.php";
});
```